# ActivatedRoute isn't getting tracked correctly for multi-tiered nav

Tags: angular

I'm using *router.navigate* in my app and it doesn't seem like the *ActivatedRoute* is tracking correctly. First, I lazy load an initial module from *app-routing.module*:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'menu-configuration',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./menu-configuration/menu-configuration.module').then(
        p => p.MenuConfigurationModule
      )
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

And then here are the routes in that module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MenuConfigurationComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'account',
        component: AccountComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'account',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'profile',
            component: ProfileComponent
          }
        ]
      }
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'account',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Here's the routing code in my *MenuComponent*:

```
this.router
  .navigate([this.itemSelected.code], {
    relativeTo: this.route
  });
```

I inject the *ActivatedRoute* into the constructor of my *NavigationMenuComponent*:

```
constructor(
 private route: ActivatedRoute,
 private router: Router,
 service: MenuItemsService
) {
  this.menuItems = service.getMenuItems();
}
```

When I click to load the *PlanConfigurationModule* the url correctly becomes this:

```
http://localhost:{port}/menu-configuration/hsa
```

Then I click on the *account* link and the url correctly becomes this:

```
http://localhost:{port}/menu-configuration/account
```

But when I try to click into an *account* child I get an error that it can't match any routes for this:

```
menu-configuration/profile
```

Why isn't this the url?

```
menu-configuration/account/profile
```

I'm routing relative to the activated route. When I'm sitting on this page:

```
http://localhost:{port}/menu-configuration/account
```

...shouldn't the activated route include the *account* portion? I'm probably just misunderstanding how this works. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you setting `this.route`? Possibly only being set once and not being reset.

Comment: I'm passing it as as dependency in my NavigationMenuComponent. I've added the code and the component tree above.

Comment: Have you tried using relative routing for the input? `/${this.categorySelected.code` Their docs specify a single parent using a relative route. It may just be the it only provide a single level relative route though, though I'm not incredibly familiar.

Comment: i don't understand your syntax. I have tried relative routing using './' + this.categorySelected.code....but it still is missing the "fsa" directory that it needs to get to the right place.

Comment: I missed the `.`, sorry. I'd have to assume that this is likely due to relativeTo being used for a single level. Probably need to create your own relativeTo for multiple levels, though I may be wrong. Your routing doesn't appear to have any issues, and you're using the routing correctly as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For now I may just use navigateByUrl() -- even though it's not the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Man i don't understand everything as well but lets start working on your lazy load.

this will create YOURurl/plan-configuration

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'plan-configuration',loadChildren: './plan-configuration/plan-configuration.module#PlanConfigurationModule'
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

on the plan-configuration module will be this

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
         path: 'fsa',
        component: RaFsaComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'hsa',
        component: HsaComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'client-profile',
        component: ClientProfileComponent
      }
];
```

### YOUR URLS WILL BE THIS

YOURurl/plan-configuration/FSA

---

YOURurl/plan-configuration/hsa

---

YOURurl/plan-configuration/client-profile

---

if you want to lazy load the client-profile and if you want this url  **YOURurl/plan-configuration/FSA/client-profile** , you will need a 2 new modules one for FSA and one client-profile.

And the old plan-configuration module will be like this

```js
 const routes: Routes = [
          {
             path: 'fsa',
            loadChildren: './thePATHforIt/fsa.module#FsaModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'hsa',
            component: HsaComponent
          }
        
      
    ];
```

**and the 2 news modules will be like this**

**1#  FSA**

```js
 const routes: Routes = [
      {
             path: '',
            component: FsaComponent
          },
      {
        path: 'client-profile',
            loadChildren: './thePATHforIt/client-profile.module#ClientProfileModule'
      }
    ];
```

**2# client-profile**

```js
 const routes: Routes = [
          {
                 path: 'client-profile',
                component: ClientProfileComponent
              }
        ];
```

Comment: Thank you for posting but I have a question: why do I need a module for every url segment? I'm trying to lazy load "fsa" and I want the url "fsa/client-profile". Why can't "fsa" be the only module and "client-profile" simply be a component? It's not big enough to warrant being its own module. It's just a form.

Comment: you can do it bro, instead of creating the 2# client-profile module. you could do on the 1# FSA module like this bellow. i'm only showed u how to lazy load whatever page u want 
@fumeng

Comment: 1# FSA module importing  client-profile directly

-------------------------------------

const routes: Routes = [
      {
             path: '',
            component: FsaComponent
          },
      {
            path: 'client-profile',
            component: ClientProfileComponent
      }
    ];